# Server sometimes doesn't receives e-mail, with error 451

Tags: smtp, email-server, gmail

One of my customers tried to send me an e-mail with his e-mail address that I didn't received. He received a Delivery Status Notification (Delay). I only received the message 2 days later

In the Delivery Status notification is marked :

```
Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     hidden@myhiddendomain.com

Message will be retried for 6 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain outbounds200.obsmtp.com by outbounds200.obsmtp.com. [207.126.147.11].

The error that the other server returned was:
451 Cannot connect to domain:myhiddenserver.com - psmtp
```

Any idea why this happens? I checked intodns, everything seams normal. I tried with other accounts (iCloud, gmail etc, I receive them all.) And this person as no trouble sending e-mails to other people.

How can I check that my server is properly configured to receive mails from everywhere?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information, such as what email server you're running, what OS you're running etc. Error 451 means it was rejected by your server due to a local issue, you may want to check your logs to see if anything is showing up around that time.

Comment: I'm running a simple WHM server with exam and dovecot

Comment: Is there anything in the logs around the time of the incident?

Comment: I'll have a look, In the error message, it looks like it is outbounds200.obsmtp.com that is issuing the error, I'm not the admin of outbounds200.obsmtp.com